# How to put the caption below the listing?

Tags: listings, captions

When I use a simple caption, tex puts it above the listing

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={My Caption}]
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image]

If I use `\captionof`, caption goes below the listing, but paragraph for next line doesn't work.

```
\begin{lstlisting}
Listing example
\end{lstlisting}
\captionof{lstlisting}{My caption}

Next line, Next line, Next line, Next line.
```

[image]

As you see, there is not a paragraph.

Comment: listings has an option to change the position of the caption. Look in the documentation, sec  5.7 Captions.

Comment: Can you send me the link?

Comment: Use `texdoc listings`, or search in the doc-folder of your texsystem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the topic could be solved by comments (and the O.P. was able to find it too)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer how is this off-topic? self answering questions is absolutely encouraged, and this is a valid question. Only problem is that the answer is edited in instead of being posted as answer...

Comment: @TheFlow0360: The O.P. did not answer his question however. If you don't agree, cast a reopen vote

Answer (score 108):

[Answer from OP, originally edited into question]

I found a solution.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={My Caption},captionpos=b]
```

Comment: @community it would help how solution is found (i.e. docuemntation references)

Comment: @Rodrigo Find the "listings" package in ctan.org (or search for "ctan lstlisting" in a search engine and find the first ctan link) then click on "Package documentation". This works for any LaTeX packages available in CTAN.